# "substitute" vs. "substituent"

Tags: difference

Could these two words be used interchangeably?

It seems that both derive from the same verb "substitute".
I didn't find an example that could resolve my doubts.
I conjecture that the word "substituent" belong to specialized vocabulary as there are not so many results as in case of "substitute". But it is still only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Substituent' is indeed specialized vocablulary. As [various dictionaries show](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/substituent), it is used only in the field of chemistry. They are not equivalent in meaning.

(Substituent has a meaning as an adjective, but that's not the issue here.)

Comment: Thank you for help.